# How to configure Apache to dispatch websocket requests on default port

Tags: apache, websocket

I have an Apache server running for normal web pages on port 80. How can apache be configured to dispatch requests for a web socket call to my WS server. The client code looks like :-

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
        window.onload = function() {
        webSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
           console.log("Got echo: " + e.data);
        }
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WebSocket Echo Client</h1>
  <button onclick='webSocket.send("Hello, world!");'>
     Send Hello
  </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can the WS server run on the same port and apache just dispatch accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want mod_proxy_wstunnell -- Apache will proxy the websockets upgraded connection w/o a secnd port, over to your other server [which must be on its own port]